# How to disable header repeat in new page mpdf library?

Tags: php, mpdf

I add `<table repeat_header="0" >` but it doesn't work for me. I want thead html tag only show in first page.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
....
</table>
```

My mpdf config is:

```
 $mpdf = new mPDF('s');
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $file_name = $_SESSION["file_name"];
    $html = $_SESSION['pdf'];
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output($file_name, 'F');
    $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more to work with. Can you please show more of your work?

Comment: repeat_header was apparently removed in v5.4. https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/323 work around it by adding logic to your code, or simply dont output what you dont want (i.e delete it)

Comment: how to setup my header doesn't repeat?

Comment: can you show your code, if your looping out the tables, add an if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `<thead>` element, use only simple table row with `<th>` cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Handle</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
....
</table>
```

There is no other way to achieve this in mPDF.

Answer (score -1):

vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Tag\THead.php 
vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Tag\TFoot.php

$this->mpdf->tablethead = 1; to  --> $this->mpdf->tablethead = 0;

$this->mpdf->tabletfoot = 1; to  --> $this->mpdf->tabletfoot = 0;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).